# How can I send attachment with ssmtp in Linux?

Tags: email, mail-user-agent, ssmtp

I can send email from my gmail account by ssmtp in Linux now. But how can I attach files to the email?

Comment: swaks : https://jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/faq.html#send_html_email   should do the trick, and is built for automation as that seems to be your goal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To send an attachment, you need to encode the message using [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME).

You could use [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/)

```
mutt -s SUBJECT -a ATTACHMENT_FILE_1 ATTACHMENT_FILE_2 -- EMAIL_ADDRESS < MESSAGE_FILE
```

or [mpack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpack)

```
mpack -s SUBJECT -D MESSAGE_FILE ATTACHMENT_FILE EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

See also:

- [How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line)
- [How to send mail from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line)
- [Sending email with attachments on UNIX systems](http://www.panix.com/~kylet/unix-att.html)

Comment: Thanks. So is that to say that it is NOT possible to send an attachment by ssmtp alone?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd have to generate all the MIME headers somehow.  Why do you need to only use `ssmtp`?  If `ssmtp` provides `/usr/lib/sendmail` or `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, any local mail program should be able to send via `ssmtp`.

Comment: @deepsky ssmtp is not a user interface. It's an MTA (mail transport agent), which is infrastructure meant to be accessed via an MUA (mail user agent, also known as a "mailreader"). It's sort of impressive that you were able to wrangle ssmtp by yourself without an MUA, but it's not a reasonable method of doing things. It's a good network-debugging skill you've learned though!

Answer (score 26):

```
echo -e "to: receiver@domain.tld\nsubject: subject\n"| (cat - && uuencode /path/to/attachment attachment.name) | ssmtp receiver@gmail.com
```

This solution does not depend on mutt.

Comment: How is this getting a negative vote? it solves the problem.

Comment: By the way, SSMTP is used by many people to send automated E-mails through Gmail: http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-with-gmail-and-ssmtp/

Comment: I know this answer came in over a year after the question was asked, but this is the answer to the question. Works great, thanks.

Comment: 4 years later, July 2017 - This is the answer I was looking for.  Thank you, @metrix!

Comment: missing uuencode command

Comment: See section about cat - && uuencode /path/to/attachment

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo -e "to: receiver@domain.tld\nsubject: test\n"| (cat - && uuencode /path/to/file file.name) | ssmtp sender@gmail.com
```

Provided that SSMTP is configured, and you've verified that messages without attachments are reaching their destination and does not depend on mutt.

Comment: I don't think this answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ sudo apt-get install uudeview
 $ echo -e "From: myaddress@mydomain.com\nTo: youraddress@yourdomain.com\nSubject: mySubject\n\nBody-Text"|uuenview -a -bo MyAttachment|sendmail -t
```

Answer (score 0):

another alternative to uuencode is to use base64 commend instead ->

```
cat msg_source.txt | (cat - base64 && attachment.bin) | ssmtp -vvvv email@domain.com
```

where **msg_source.txt** contains header tags, like To:, From:, Subject:, Content-Type:, etc