# SSMTP: How to send email with both a body and attachment

Tags: email, ssmtp

I am currently using the following command to send emails from my Ubuntu server, which I adapted from this question's answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90881/166614

```
printf "subject: the subject\n\nMessage body"| (cat - && uuencode "$attach" $(basename "$attach")) | ssmtp <email>
```

My only problem so far is that the command above creates two attachments consisting of the file indicated by the $attach variable and a text file containing what's supposed to be the message body with a seemingly random number for a name. If I remove the `(cat - && uuencode "$attach" $(basename "$attach"))` command, the email has a body as it should but (obviously) no attachment. Conversely, if I remove the body, the text file attchment is not present.

Does anyone know how I can send an email through SSMTP with both a body and attachment?

Comment: Read the answer using Mutt and apply it to your situation.  Alternatively, read the MIME RFCs and learn how to create MIME-compliant attachments.  Then go to the answer referring you to `uuencode` and downvote it, since it's already 2016 AD. :)

Comment: While I could use Mutt to do what I need, I would rather not if possible. Linux philosophy, after all, is to keep it simple; I only need to send emails whereas Mutt is a full-blown email client with functionality I really don't need on a headless server. Besides, Mutt _requires_ the installation of a Sendmail compatible SMTP agent to send emails, so why not just interact with the SMTP agent directly?

Comment: _Linux philosophy, after all, is to keep it simple_ - Absolutely; anybody who disagrees should just take a look at `systemd(8)`. Anyway, you still have plan B: read the RFC and create a valid message.  It isn't _that_ hard for the simplest cases.  You need to generate a boundary and a few headers.  _Mutt requires the installation of a Sendmail compatible SMTP agent to send emails_ - Mutt _can_ use `ssmtp`.  You just need to configure it. _why not just interact with the SMTP agent directly?_ - Because then you'd also need to read the SMTP RFC, and apply it correctly?

Comment: And as for creating MIME-compliant attachments, all of the material I've read says that this is what `uuencode` does. For example, this answer uses it to help create a MIME compliant email: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11725308/6627890 . Unfortunately, I just created a test script using that answer and it didn't work at all; in the received test email, the body's text has disappeared and the raw text representing the attachment was pasted into the body.

Comment: _And as for creating MIME-compliant attachments, all of the material I've read says that this is what `uuencode` does._ - Then you misunderstand what MIME compliance is about. _shrug_

Comment: `uuencode` generates an inline encoding of a file, and was invented back in the dark days before MIME. In such emails there were no body or attachment parts, there was only email. These days we have MIME, and strangely we no longer have body parts (to emails). Rather, emails contain one or more attachments and a mail client is expected to know which text attachment is to be treated as a body and displayed as such.

Comment: I do prefer using `mpack` to send MIME mails over the command line.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I took a look at `mpack` and it was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately decided to use `mpack` to accomplish this task. While this doesn't answer the exact question I posed, I think `mpack` provides a simple way of sending emails without installing email clients with functionality that you might not need.
That said, if anyone can answer the exact question, they are welcome to post it.

This is the command I'm now using to send an email from the command line with a body and attachment:

```
attachment=/location/of/attachment
printf "Body text here." | mpack -a -s "Subject here" -d /dev/stdin -m 0 -c $(file -b --mime-type $attachment) "$attachment" <email address>
```

Comment: several of that options are assumed by default, you do not need such a complex command line

Comment: The only options I see which might be regarded as unnecessary are -a, -m and -c. I use -a because the man pages explicitly say that the attachment will be treated as inline without it which is not what I want. Fair enough with -m, I just included it in case someone looking at my answer has the environment variable that this parameter reads set to something that is inappropriate. As for -c, when I tested, I was attaching a zip archive and it was labelled in the received email as an octet-stream whereas with the command I used with -c, it was correctly labelled as a zip-archive.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how to do it:**

[Simplest way to send mail with image attachment from command line using gmail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381131/simplest-way-to-send-mail-with-image-attachment-from-command-line-using-gmail)

---

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpack

mpack -s "Subject line" -d body.txt attachment.png abd@def.com
```

**Couldn't be simpler.**

---

If you like shorter command lines, you can put your subject line into the body file, like so:

message.txt contents:

```
SUBJECT:  P&L Chart for board meeting this Tuesday
(blank line is required here)
Hello Mr. Jarvis,
blah, blah, blah
```

Command line:

```
mpack -d message.txt plchart.jpg jarvis@company.com
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the exact conclusion I ultimately arrived at in the end, as noted above.