# File not attached while send HTML email in Bash

Tags: bash, email, html

File is not attached while send in HTML email Bash

Below is my sample script ,while executing the script the mail was sent with out an attachment.
Please help.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
FOUND_EMAIL_TEXT="This is an automated report generated .
Please investigate and remediate them as soon as possible."
 (
             echo "From: xyz@abc.com"
             echo "To: xyz@abc.com"
             echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
             echo "Subject: Test Email"
             echo "Content-Type: text/html"
             echo "<FONT FACE='COURIER NEW' SIZE='5'>;<PRE>"
             echo -e "${FOUND_EMAIL_TEXT}
             echo "</PRE><;/FONT>;"
             echo "Content-Type: text/html"
             echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'/ght.txt/'"'
                echo "$(cat /home/dfg/ter.txt)"
) | sendmail -t
```

Comment: You have a missing quote on the `echo -e "${FOUND_EMAIL_TEXT}` line. Is that a typo here in your question or is it part of your script?

Comment: Typo here,just corrected it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some better options for encoding email attachments than uuencode in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378066/what-are-some-better-options-for-encoding-email-attachments-than-uuencode-in-a-b)

Comment: In the proposed duplicate take a particular look at the [answer recommending `mpack`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378081/100397)

Comment: Actually, I think this one's a better fit for duplicate status - [How to send email with both a body and attachment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309052/100397)